# The index of $R \subset R[\beta]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Consider the order $R=\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt[4]{-19}) \subset K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{-19}) $. Let $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{-19}$ and $\beta=(\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1)/2$. My question is:

> How do we compute the index of $R \subset R[\beta]$?

The discriminant $\Delta(R)=\Delta(X^4+19)=2^8\cdot 19^3$ and $\Delta(R) = [R[\beta]:R]^2 \cdot \Delta(R[\beta])$. Therefore if we can compute the discriminant of $R[\beta]$ then we get the index. However i find $\Delta(R[\beta])$ so complicated. Maybe we have another approach to know $[R[\beta]:R]$ then can figure out $\Delta(R[\beta])$.

Comment: It seems that $\beta$ is not integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, so it cannot be integral over $R$ (foolows from transitivity property of integrality, since $R$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$). It is quite possible that your index is infinite, but I may be wrong. Do you have any reason to believe this index is finite ?

Comment: The element $\beta$ is definitely integral over $\bf Z$. You could try to compute the discriminant of $R[\beta]$ using the ${\bf Z}$=basis $1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\beta$.

Comment: My bad, I did a mistake in the computation of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$: it is indeed integral over $\mathbb{Z}$...